# Java : Implicit cast of Object at compile-time doesn't work but work with reflection

Tags: java, object, reflection, casting, compiler-errors

Given the following code :

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Test {

  public static void test_function(int[] values) {
    System.out.println("Class of values : " + values.getClass());
    System.out.println(values[0]);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Object a = Array.newInstance(int.class, 3);
    Array.set(a, 0, 5);

    Class a_class         = a.getClass();
    Class int_array_class = int[].class;

    System.out.println("Class of int[]  : " + int[].class); 
    System.out.println("Class of a      : " + a.getClass());
    System.out.println("int_array_class : " + int_array_class);
    System.out.println("a_class         : " + a_class);

    // These instructions will provoke a compile-time error
    // test_function(a);
    // test_function(a_class.cast(a));
    // test_function(int_array_class.cast(a));

    // The following call won't cause any problem
    test_function((int[]) a);

    Method testf = null;
    try { 
      testf = Test.class.getMethod("test_function", int[].class);
      testf.invoke(null, a); // Does not provoke exception at run-time either
      testf.invoke(null, a_class.cast(a));
      testf.invoke(null, int_array_class.cast(a));
    }
    catch(Exception e) { 
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

I noticed that passing explicitly an Object to a method doesn't work. The three commented instructions will provoke the following error if uncommented :

```
Test.java:25: error: method test_function in class Test cannot be applied to given types;
    test_function(a);
    ^
  required: int[]
  found: Object
  reason: actual argument Object cannot be converted to int[] by method invocation conversion
Test.java:26: error: method test_function in class Test cannot be applied to given types;
    test_function(a_class.cast(a));
    ^
  required: int[]
  found: Object
  reason: actual argument Object cannot be converted to int[] by method invocation conversion
Test.java:27: error: method test_function in class Test cannot be applied to given types;
    test_function(int_array_class.cast(a));
    ^
  required: int[]
  found: Object
  reason: actual argument Object cannot be converted to int[] by method invocation conversion
3 errors
```

However, passing the objects through reflection work fine and produce the expected results.

```
Class of int[]  : class [I
Class of a      : class [I
int_array_class : class [I
a_class         : class [I
Class of values : class [I
5
Class of values : class [I
5
Class of values : class [I
5
Class of values : class [I
5
```

**So the question is : Why is the compiler refusing to compile the three commentend instructions that work fine at run-time ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reflectional access is able to determine the actual type of objects *at runtime*. The compiler on the other hand only knows about declared types. It does not have any other possibility of inspecting the actual type of arguments.

Your variable `a` is declared as `Object`. Therefore with

```
test_function(a);
```

you try to call a method with the signature `void test_function(Object)` that simply does not exist. A simple cast - as you as the programmer know the correct type - will help here:

```
test_function((int[]) a); // works fine (even at runtime)
```

The other two method calls are the same, but yet a bit different. You declared `a_class` and `int_array_class` with the type `Class`. That is a raw type, so the compiler does not know which type of class these variable could refer to. The compiler *must* infer type `Object`. That leads to the same problem (and solution) as before.

However, `Class` is a generic type and can be parameterized. With the following change the last method call works without *explicit* casting:

```
Class<int[]> int_array_class = int[].class;
test_function(int_array_class.cast(a));
```

Comment: Can you tell me how this implicit type casting is happening? I want to know how can I do that myself

Answer (score 0):

test_function expects an int[] as argument, you are passing it an object reference(Object a). No wonder it does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Your three commented out functions require explicit casts to `int[]` to compile. Like this,

```
test_function((int[]) a);
test_function((int[]) a_class.cast(a));
test_function((int[]) int_array_class.cast(a));
```

They ran without exception when I tested them on Java 8.